# Как на Python выбрать все значения определенного столбца в таблице базы данных SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть таблица в базе данных SQLite. Я хотел перебрать все значения определенного столбца в цикле. Каким образом мне составить SQLite запрос?

Comment: Элементарный select. С чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: Пытался найти такой пример, но не получилось. Я только видел примеры, где перебирали все значения таблицы(а не определенного столбца) и примеры, где использовали WHERE column=?, я думаю, мне это не подходит

Comment: А учебник или хотя бы краткое руководство по SQL пробовали прочитать?

Comment: Я смотрел всю первую страницу, которую мне выдал гугл по запросу python sqlite

Comment: Попробуйте повторить для запроса "sql".

Comment: Думал, что конкретно для python есть какие-то различия, хорошо, спасибо, буду смотреть

Comment: Select myslotbicheckname from table;

Comment: Спасибо большое:)

Comment: _Я только видел примеры, где перебирали все значения таблицы, а не определенного столбца_, и в итоге приняли ответ как правильный, который как раз  этому критерию не соответствует. Почему?

Comment: Потому что этому вопросу уже больше полугода. Я разобрался с ним в тот же день, когда и задал. Поэтому я уже сам не помню чего тогда хотел. Человек потратил время, написал ответ, поэтому я решил, что нужно сказать ему спасибо таким способом :) Закрывать вопрос не стал, в комментариях под ним был правильный ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sql.execute("SELECT Название столбца FROM Название Таблицы")
#sql - это ваш cursor
massive = sql.fetchone()#этот метод вернет вам один кортеж с только одной строкой из базы
massive_big = sql.fetchall()#этот метод вернет вам все элементы в одном кортеже. Данные из строк будут представлены как вложенные кортежи
#перебираем обычный кортеж, просто печатаем элементы кортежа
for i in range(len(massive)):
    print(massive[i])
#перебираем кортеж с кортежами внутри, также печатаем элементы
for z in range(len(massiv_big)):
    print(massive_big[i][0])
```

Print'ы в циклах замените на то, что вам нужно сделать с полученными данными.
Спасибо [0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217579/0xdb) за то, что указал на мою ошибку в SQL-коде.

Comment: Извините, а как выше сообшение отвечет на вопрос ТС в этом топике?

Comment: Все просто - человеку нужно получить все значения из определенного столбца. Я показал, как это можно сделать, также показал пример перебора данных в цикле.
Вопросы?

Comment: _все значения определенного столбца_,  и у вас в коде - `SELECT * FROM`, вы знаете что это значит?

Comment: Ах да. Я просто забыл что мы обращаемся к таблице в FROM, а не к столбцу. Спасибо за то, что поправили)